# What is the difference among eval(parse()), eval(str2lang()), eval(str2expression()), and eval(call()[[1]])?

Tags: r, eval

I'm writing a function to extract a variable provided as a string from either a given data.frame `df` or the environment `env`. Initially, I had been using the `eval(parse(text=s), df, env)` construction to do this, but I learned that there are more efficient alternatives. Other options include:

1. `eval(str2lang(s), df, env)`
2. `eval(str2expression(s), df, env)`
3. `eval(call(s)[[1]], df, env)`

There may be a `get` solution as well, but I don't know if it can check to see if the variable is in `df` first before turning to `env` if it isn't.

Using `microbenchmark`, it seems that `call` is the fastest:

```r
library(microbenchmark)

x1 = 1
df = data.frame(x2 = 2)

microbenchmark(call = eval(call('x1')[[1]], df), 
               parse = eval(parse(text='x1'), df), 
               str2lang = eval(str2lang('x1'), df), 
               str2exp = eval(str2expression('x1'), df), 
               check = "identical")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>      expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
#>      call  1.128  1.2115  1.60815  1.4585  1.6360   4.659   100  a 
#>     parse 39.183 39.8705 46.60755 40.2405 42.0415 135.462   100   b
#>  str2lang  2.235  2.3570  3.26144  2.5995  2.8925  24.641   100  a 
#>   str2exp  2.230  2.3200  2.81387  2.4780  2.6970  10.312   100  a

microbenchmark(call = eval(call('x2')[[1]], df), 
               parse = eval(parse(text='x2'), df), 
               str2lang = eval(str2lang('x2'), df), 
               str2exp = eval(str2expression('x2'), df), 
               check = "identical")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>      expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
#>      call  1.124  1.194  1.47770  1.3675  1.5795   9.031   100  a 
#>     parse 38.254 38.762 40.21497 38.9630 39.3120 116.510   100   b
#>  str2lang  2.214  2.304  2.55036  2.3960  2.6530  10.639   100  a 
#>   str2exp  2.238  2.331  2.50011  2.4210  2.6515   3.619   100  a
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I'm therefore inclined to use `call` but I want to make sure there wouldn't be any unintended consequences of doing so rather than using the other solutions. In other words, in what situations (within the context I'm using them in) would the four methods not give the same answer, leading one to favor one over the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `call` and `as.symbol` are fine, I think `as.symbol` is preferable. `as.symbol` is unambiguous R terminology (`as.name` was S terminology) and is as fast as `call`.  A call can contain any R object, including symbols and other calls, plus documentation is all over the place. Because the strings could contain punctuation we can not be sure at which point `str2lang`, or `str2expression` fail or what error message might pop up.

Checking if variables exist in an environment is safer than doing so for data.frames.

### Differences

a look under the hood reveals main differences are in their classes:

```r
l = list(w = as.symbol("x"), x = str2lang("x"), y = str2expression("x"), z = call("x"))
rbind(sapply(l, class), sapply(l, typeof), sapply(l, is.language))
     w        x        y            z         
[1,] "name"   "name"   "expression" "call"    
[2,] "symbol" "symbol" "expression" "language"
[3,] "TRUE"   "TRUE"   "TRUE"       "TRUE"
```

A good starting point is the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Language-objects), and for examples the Expressions chapter in Hadley Wickham's *Advanced R* ([source](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html)), followed by reading `?call`, `?parse`, `rlang::call2`.

#### What are they?

In *Evaluating the Design of the R Language* ([source](http://janvitek.org/pubs/ecoop12.pdf)) the following definition is given: 
                                Arguments of *calls* are *expressions* which may be named by a symbol <del>name</del>.

- **Expression** - *an action* or *actions*.
- **Call** - represent the *action of calling a function*.
- **Symbols (Name)** - *refer* to R objects ([2.1.3](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Language-objects))

### Which one to use when?

From the `?call` documentation:

> Instead of `as.call(<string>)`, consider using `str2lang(*)` which is an efficient version of `parse(text=*)`. `call()` and `as.call()`, are much preferable to `parse()` based approaches.

Using `pryr::show_c_source(.Internal(str2lang(s)))` we can see that `str2lang` and `str2expression` both call
the [C function](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2b0818a47199a0b64b6aa9b9f0e53a1e886e8e95/src/main/coerce.c#L1665-L1681) `do_str2lang` but differ in their argument. This difference can be found in `?parse`:

- `str2expression`, equal to `parse(text = "x", keep.source = F)` is always an expression.
- `str2lang("x")`, equal to `parse(text = "x", keep.source = F)[[1]]` can evaluate to a call **OR** a symbol, `NULL`, numeric, integer or logical, i.e. *a call or simpler*.

In the *R Language Definition* it is mentioned that expressions are only evaluated when passed to `eval`, other language objects may get evaluated in some unexpected cases. What these cases are, I could not find.

We can throw some edge cases at all approaches to see when which might fail:

- `"\""` wrongly parsed quote when reading in data?
- `" "` empty variable? space in variable name?
- `"_"` illegal token (legacy assignment operator) issues?
- backtick
- NA

```r
# if it breaks, show how it breaks
do <- function(x, ...) tryCatch(eval(x, ..1, ..2), error = function(t) t$message)
check <- function(x, ...){
  list(
    do(call(x)[[1]], ...),
    do(as.symbol(x), ...),
    do(str2lang(x), ...),
    do(str2expression(x), ...)
  )
}

# test 1: some variables do not exist
e <- new.env() ; e$x1 <- 5
df = data.frame(x2 = 3)
no_var <- lapply(list("x1", "x2", "\"", " ", "_", "`", NA_character_), check, df, e)

# test 2: some variables exist
e <- new.env() ; e$x1 = 5; e$`_` = 2 ; e$"\"" = 5; e$`NA` <- 5
df = data.frame(x2 = 3, " " = 7, "_" = 2)
var <- lapply(list("x1", "x2", "\"", " ", "_", "`", NA_character_), check, df, e)

# difference in outcomes in
var[3:7]
no_var[3:7]
```

When variables do not exist:
`as.symbol` and `call` always reach `eval`, `str2lang` and `str2expression` fail early in all cases. `str2expression` differs from `str2lang` when an empty string is given.

When variables exist:
`as.symbol` and `call` succeed in cases 3, 4, 7 while `str2lang` and `str2expression` throw errors.

On a sidenote, be careful with storing variables in data.frames, they are easy to corrupt.

```
names(data.frame(" " = 1, "_" = 2, "\"" = 3, "`" = 4))
[1] "X."   "X_"   "X..1" "X..2"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what strings you are trying to evaluate.  If it's always a single name, then `as.name('x1')` is probably a contender as well; my tests show it just a little slower than your solution with `call`, but I'd say it's preferable just because it's less obscure, and less likely to cause future headaches.

The headaches might arise because of this:  currently `call("x1")` produces the language object `x1()`, and then you extract the name of the function being called.  But what if in some future version of R it remembers that the `x1` in that expression is supposed to be a function?  `eval(x1())` already knows to ignore non-function objects named `x1`, so it's not going to break much code to make that change, and it might be useful from an efficiency point of view.

`as.name` also allows non-character arguments, e.g. `as.name(123)`; this could be positive or negative for you.  (Both solutions would allow `"123"`.)