# r data.table row subset with column name as a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Let's first create a simple data.table in r.

```
dt=data.table(x1=1:5,
           x2=11:21)
```

If we want to subset the data.table with conditions for rows, we can simple do, for example

```
dt[x1==1]
```

Now my question is: what if the column name is a variable ? I tried with :

```
var="x1"
dt[eval(var)==1,]
```

But this code doesn't work.

`eval` works with the following example: if we want to get the some columns by name (that is a variable).

```
dt[x1==1,eval(var),with=F]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/select-assign-to-data-table-when-variable-names-are-stored-in-a-character-vect

Comment: Any of the following work with data.table 1.14.8 `var <- "x1"` `dt[eval(as.name(var)) == 1]`, `dt[eval(as.symbol(var)) == 1]` (as.name is an old version of as.symbol), `dt[get(var) == 1]` (as stated in both answers), `dt[eval(call(var)[[1]]) == 1]`, `dt[eval(parse(text = var)) == 1]`, `dt[eval(str2lang(var)) == 1]`, `dt[eval(str2expression(var)) == 1]`. I think the `str2` methods are the preferred option as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61380829/what-is-the-difference-among-evalparse-evalstr2lang-evalstr2expressio).

Comment: More methods using packages can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `get`:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(x1=1:11, x2=11:21)
var <- "x1"
DT[get(var)==1,]
```

Comment: Note that this only works if `DT` has no column named `var`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The same restriction applies to @akrun's answer.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `.SD`

```
 DT[DT[, .SD[[var]] ==1]]
   x1 x2
1:  1 11
```

which gives the same output as the accepted answer

```
 DT[get(var)==1,]
   x1 x2
1:  1 11
```